# UIButton not displaying background image on device or simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, storyboard, xcode6

I really thought stuff like this wouldn't happen to me, but here it is:

I Setup some Buttons on the StoryBoard. When I Compile the App into a Device or the Simulator, one of the Buttons shows the Image and the Rest don't.

I Already Checked that the Images are assigned to the Target and that the Resources appear on the Project.

Any Ideas?

[image: WAT?]

Comment: It´s easier to help you if your screenshot include the attributes inspector view of a button.

Comment: Tell me you are using UIButton on UILabels to set text(signup, login)? or you have set the title of UIButton?

Comment: click on sign up button and show what you have in Inspector in screenshot... problem is in layout or in IB there...

Comment: I think your autolayout is not set properly.

Comment: @Maverick : yes, constraint is issue.. check his log statements...

Comment: can you tell me what you have in Mode for UIButton? It should be scale to fill... I think you have Center...

Comment: OP, would you mind in reply?

Comment: Hi @Maverick. I Think you are Right... Must be the Constraints. I'll check them Out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is Embarrassing.

Turns out I Was Modifying the superview.bounds Due to a Previous Interface Issues and i Forgot About them.

The Problematic Code:

// to Arrange the Layout:
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];
    self.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 356, 421);
}

So I Removed This Line: self.view.superview.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 356, 421); and Everything is now OK.

Lesson: DO NOT PLAY WITH THE BOUNDS OF YOUR SUPERVIEW IF YOU WANT AUTOLAYOUT TO WORK.

Thanks to @Maverick and @Fahim Parkar for pointing me on the Right Direction :-)